# How to reset PayPal next billing date?

Tags: paypal, subscription

I am using monthly and yearly PayPal subscriptions in my application.
I want to reset my PayPal subscription billing date.

Reason: My problem is a subs/paypal issue.
I want If I increase the subscription end date by 1 or 2 months in my DB, the user's PayPal account should not be charged with PayPal 1 or 2 months before the subscription of DB is completed.
I am not sure it is possible, but I should solve this problem.
How can I reset the paypal billing date?

Answer (score 0):

You can update or suspend and later re-activate the subscription. There are API calls for this.

Update: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_patch

Suspend: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_suspend

Comment: Hi @Preston. Thanks for your answer. I want to call the update API if it is possible. But I don't know which attribute needs to be updated to change the next billing date.  `start_time` ?

Comment: After days of investigation, I realized that there is no valid way to change the next billing date, while this kind of scenario exists in real-life business. For example, I might provide a free week to a user in the middle of his subscription. To handle this kind of case, we need to suspend the subscription for a week and re-activate it after a week. Because there is not an automatic trigger to reactivate, this is a pain.